# visual studio 2013 reset text zoom for all files

Tags: visual-studio-2013, zooming

I just got prescription glasses and I have to zoom out each document independently. Is there way to reset text zoom to whole project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found this addon and it offers synchronized zooming http://vscommands.squaredinfinity.com/Features-Zoom

Answer (score 0):

You can increase default VS environment font size or install the [Global Zoom Level](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/59260ee8-5e2d-4ca7-8dc5-4efcf7b61a81) extension.

Comment: well that's not what i was looking for, i needed something like shared zoom settings, because i have many documents with different zoom levels